# Issues in ssis when converting data types

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, data-conversion, ssis-data-types

Hi am having trouble understanding data conversion in ssis. when should one convert data types,should I always convert or I only convert when ssis has data type compatibility issues?

Am struggling to understand if i should convert when i import from excel to sql server or from sql server to excel or from text file file to sql server or from sql server to text file etc?

Please help me understanding data conversion in ssis.

Comment: SSIS is very rigid with it's data. I, personally, prefer to always explicitly convert my values when it needs to be changed from the source and the destination, rather than relying on an implicit conversion (which might error). This, however, is more a question of preference; which is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: So everytime I import data from an external source I should always convert it before performing anything on it or should I perform stuff on the data and convert only when I want to write the data to a destination

Comment: I didn't say that. However, that statement is far to broad to be answered, especially on Stack Overflow. SO is for asking specific coding questions. if you're having a particular problem with a data flow task, you would be better off asking about that (by deleting this question and creating a new one); not asking a very broad and opinionated question.

Comment: Hi @TebogoKgengwe as it happens typically in IT, the answer is it depends. If your quality assurance fails, or you get errors, you should convert, otherwise do not bother. One nuance is though: Excel is a user facing desktop application, we should not use it for data inter-exchange

Answer (score 0):

The need to convert data from one data type to another will largely be dictated by the business need for it. For example, the ID fields are usually Integers and need not be converted, but a phone number on the other hand may have "(" or hyphens that need to be removed before they are loaded onto your destination database.

SSIS offer's ways to convert data that will ultimately fit the pattern/datatype that you need it to be in. A comprehensive list of the supported data types is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-custom-objects/data-flow/working-with-data-types-in-the-data-flow?view=sql-server-2017)